# Hidden form appears in bottom left corner

Tags: .net, winforms, hide

My Windows Forms application starts another one; the latter is meant to remain hidden, and appear and disappear as the user presses the F9 key.

I need the hidden form to run in another process, so I use `Process.Start`. However, no matter what I do, I can't get the form to start hidden. It always appears in the bottom left corner, and weirdly, it only shows the title bar, from which I can maximize it. This is undesired.

I tried tweaking the `StartInfo` with `ShellExecute = false`, `CreateNoWindow = true`, `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyleHidden`, you name it.

I also tried going to the form's designer and setting `ShowInTaskbar` to false, but no cigar. One thing that drew my attention when I tried that is that the `WindowState` property could only be set to Normal, Minimized or Maximized, not Hidden.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions? (Asides from ditching Windows Forms; this is legacy code)

**Edit**: (Very important) I forgot to mention that my main app is full screen, and that the windows desktop is locked. That is, when the machine boots up, my main app is started instead of Explorer

Comment: If the hidden form is something that is part of your own code base (a task, but separate process that must run async) we can help you write async code so you don't need the separate process. Also mind you, WinForms is old now, but its definitely not legacy by any means. Is it an absolute requirement that this be a separate process in its own AppDomain?

Comment: Yes sir, it must absolutely be a separate app. Don't know about AppDomains, perhaps I should use that instead of `Process.Start()`? How?

Comment: This can only be done inside the app that you start, not from your shell replacement.  It isn't clear whether that's suitable from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a long time ago, but forgot to post my solution. The key was to have the form's created minimized. In the designer, in `InitializeComponent`, I added:

```
 TopMost = true;
 TopLevel = true;
 WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

And, for good measure, I did it once again after calling `InitializeComponent` (there is an almost imperceptible flicker but it works):

```
public void Init( bool pQueryAndRetrieveForm, ref bool pIsOpen ) {
       InitializeComponent();
       WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
       //More initialization code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Form should have a property called "Visible" If you set it to False, I am not sure it will catch your F9 key.

However, you should be able to set the Left and Top properties to values outside the screen boundaries and then restore appropriate values when needed.

Something like

```
Form1.Top= 3000
Form1.Left = 3000
```

and

```
Form1.Top = _appropriateTop
Form1.Left = _appropriateLeft
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about that property. I tried setting it to false in `InitializeComponent()`, but the CLR changes it to True somewhere along the line from the `Process.Start` call... I can set it to false as soon as I can, but then again, the form will be visible for a while... I'll consider changing the location as a last resort, there must be a more elegant solution

Comment: An alternative could be to set the Opacity property to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding a winform on startup.  This works for me.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HideThisForm));
        t.Start();
    }

    delegate void FormCallback();
    void HideThisForm()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new FormCallback(HideThisForm);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't do that, they must remain as totally separate processes. Perhaps I could launch the second application some other way, instead of using 'Process.Start'...?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking separate thread, not process.  Give the new example a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to achieve asynchronous processing?  Such as, for instance, allowing your main form to process while something else *works*? If you want to process another set of code/data asynchronously, why not set up a thread to accomplish the task for you in the background? e.g.

In C#,

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(() => DoSomethingAsync());
    }

    private void DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

This will allow your block of code to process without locking your main thread.  You can accomplish this same logic many ways, depending on your circumstances -- such as a background worker, thread pool, or one-off threads.  It all depends on your requirements.